# Problem with instanciation on FlutterBluePlus

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

im a beginner on FLutter and im trying to use FlutterBluePlus to play with BLE connection.
But when i do `FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;`

I have this error message "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. (Documentation)  Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void."

Why is it void? I'm pretty sure it is not supposed to be

I already used .instance in another project and I did not have this problem, and reading the pluggin documation didnt help either :/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state:
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue_plus/latest/flutter_blue_plus/FlutterBluePlus/instance.html

```
@Deprecated('No longer needed, remove this from your code')
static void get instance => null;
```

So this is deprecated now.
When you interact with the Plugin you no longer create a Instance e.g `FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus();`
you just use `FlutterBluePlus.isScanning` for Example